# how to compile arduino sketch from termnial without using arduino ide

Tags: arduino-ide, uploading, ide, upload

I want to know how can I compile and upload the arduino sketch from my terminal instead of using Arduino IDE. I want to use a different IDE for writing code.

Comment: https://blog.arduino.cc/2018/08/24/announcing-the-arduino-command-line-interface-cli/

Comment: there's also `platformio`

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/news/2833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a contributor to [Sloeber](http://sloeber.io), an Eclipse Plugin dedicated to Arduino and other micro controllers, I can tell you it's all a matter of using the correct version of `gcc` and provide the correct options.

Even if that might seem simple, it's not like that, so my advice is to download Sloeber and look at the build console output where we print all the statements used to fulfill the build task: you can infer a lot from that.

As Sloeber is also open source, you can also inspect how we create those build commands for the different boards and tool chains.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using PlatformIO for about 2 years now I think. It’s simply amazing.

https://platformio.org

You can use it standalone just for the CLI compile or bundled with VisualCode Studio for a complete IDE solution.